# appengine - Restore to another appid

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a option to restore the backup to a different app-id.
If there is an issue with our application/data, you might want to restore to another app-id and try to fix the data issues.

-Aswath

Answer (score 0):

Data- No (Unless you have maintained versions using Namespaces, which is too unlikely)
App- Yes if you have maintained versions at various points during deploy!

Answer (score 0):

Not presently, no. With some effort you could modify the restore code to change embedded keys, which would be the main requirement for restoring to a different app.